# How can I print filled / unfilled square character using printf in c?

Tags: c

I am trying to print "□" and "■" using c.

I tried `printf("%c", (char)254u);` but it didn't work.

Any help? Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing a Unicode Symbol in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834315/printing-a-unicode-symbol-in-c). You aren't that far off, but you need a bit of extra code to be able to print Unicode (really anything non-ASCII) in C

Answer (score 2):

You can print Unicode characters using `_setmode`.

> Sets the file translation mode. [learn more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=msvc-170)

```c
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>

int main(void) {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wprintf(L"\x25A0\x25A1\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
■□
```

Comment: is _setmode a standart library function ?

Comment: @VolkanÜnal no, `_setmode` is not a standard library function.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what is `(char)254u` in your code. First you set locale to unicode, next you just `printf` it. That is it.

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");
    printf("%lc", u'□');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I copied your code but, that still didn't print anything.

Comment: @RyanLee Copy code to some online editor. For example [codechef](https://www.codechef.com/ide). See that it works. If you have some non-standard system, please tag appropriate. As of now, I mark your question as not reproducible.

Comment: Hmmm I guess yeah it might be my compiler problem.
I am using mingw64 gcc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use directly like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("■");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is my compiler problem or chip difference, but it is printing `?`.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have mentioned, you have need to set the proper locale to use the UTF-8 encoding, defined by the [Unicode Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). Then you can print it with `%lc` using any corresponding number. Here is a minimal code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8"); // Defined proper UTF-8 locale
    printf("%lc\n", 254);               // Using '%lc' to specify wchar_t instead of char 

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to store it in a variable, you must use a `wchar_t`, which allows the number to be mapped to its Unicode symbol. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27401231/understanding-and-writing-wchar-t-in-c) provides more detail.

```
wchar_t x = 254;
printf("%lc\n", x);
```